# What are GADTs?

Tags: haskell

I was reading the [GADTs for dummies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADTs_for_dummies) page on the Haskell Wiki, and I still don't understand how and why they should be used. The author provided a motivating example:

```
data T a where
    D1 :: Int -> T String
    D2 :: T Bool
    D3 :: (a,a) -> T [a]
```

What exactly does this code do and why is it useful?

If this question is a little too vague, perhaps a related question is: can GADTs be used to implement member functions?

Comment: For what it's worth, [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) has a good explanation.

Comment: That sample code really is useless to understand what they are for.

Comment: see https://vimeo.com/12208838 for explanation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lets say you want to model a Fruit bag. This bag can have apple or oranges. So as a good haskeller you define:

```
data Bag = Oranges Int | Apples Int
```

That looks nice. Let's see that `Bag` type alone without looking at the data constructors. Does `Bag` type alone gives you any indication whether it is orange bag or apple bag. Well not statically, I mean at runtime a function could pattern match on value of `Bag` type to detect whether it is oranges or apples but won't it be nice to enforce this at compile time / type check time itself, So that a function that only works with Bag of apples cannot be passed bag of oranges at all.

This is where GADTs can help us, basically allows us to be more precise about our types:

```
data Orange = ...
data Apple = ....

data Bag a where
    OrangeBag :: [Orange] -> Bag [Orange]
    AppleBag :: [Apple] -> Bag [Apple]
```

Now I can define a function which only works with bag of apples.

```
giveMeApples :: Bag [Apple] -> ...
```

Comment: Note that this particular use of GADTs can be replaced with a couple of other extensions that I don't remember off the top of my head. GADTs are much more powerful than only solving this problem, although this was a neat example.

Comment: @kqr GADTs can always be replaced with a couple other extensions, but so what?

Comment: @DanielWagner Indeed, GADTs generalise several other extensions. I was just saying that GADTs can be used for a lot more than just this example, so if you read this and think, "Sure, that's neat, but I can already do that with X and Y" you don't think GADTs are limited to this.

Comment: How is this an improvement over `Bag = Identity`?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: This won't allows you to create arbitary Bag values like `Bag Human`, which is not the case with `Identity`

Comment: This particular use doesn't require any extensions at all as long as you hide the constructors.

Comment: Based only on this example, it looks like GADTs add one of the capabilities of subtyping ("a function that only works with Bag of apples cannot be passed bag of oranges at all") to ADTs. Is there anything else GADTs add?

Answer (score 11):

GADTs allow you to have your types to contain more information about the values they represent. They do this by stretching Haskell `data` declarations a little bit of the way to the inductive type families in a dependently typed language.

The quintessential example is typed Higher Order Abstract Syntax represented as a GADT.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-} -- Not needed, just for convenience of (:@) below

module HOAS where

data Exp a where
  Lam  :: (Exp s -> Exp t) -> Exp (s -> t)
  (:@) :: Exp (s -> t) -> Exp s -> Exp t
  Con  :: a -> Exp a

intp :: Exp a -> a
intp (Con a)      = a
intp (Lam f)      = intp . f . Con
intp (fun :@ arg) = intp fun (intp arg)
```

In this example, `Exp` is a GADT. Note that the `Con` constructor is very normal, but the `App` and `Lam` constructors introduce new type variables quite freely. These are existentially quantified type variables and they represent rather complex relationships between the different arguments to `Lam` and `App`.

In particular, they ensure that any `Exp` can be interpreted as a well-typed Haskell expression. Without using GADTs we'd need to use sum types to represent the values in our terms and handle type errors.

```
>>> intp $ Con (+1) :@ Con 1
2

>>> Con (+1) :@ Con 'a'
<interactive>:1:11: Warning:
    No instance for (Num Char) arising from a use of `+'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Char)
    In the first argument of `Con', namely `(+ 1)'
    In the first argument of `App', namely `(Con (+ 1))'
    In the expression: App (Con (+ 1)) (Con 'a')

>>> let konst = Lam $ \x -> Lam $ \y -> x
>>> :t konst
konst :: Exp (t -> s -> t)

>>> :t intp $ konst :@ Con "first"
intp $ konst :@ Con "first" :: s -> [Char]

>>> intp $ konst :@ Con "first" :@ Con "second"
"first"
```

Comment: I don't see anything named "App" in your example code...?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I sort of arbitrarily changed it from `App` to `(:@)` for demonstration purposes. `(:@)` is a bit nicer to read.