# An concrete simple example to demonstrate GADT in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I've searched around for the concept of GADT **in OCaml**, why we need it and when to use it, etc.

I understand GADT is not only in OCaml but a more general term.

I've found

[What are GADTs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464410/what-are-gadts)

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc85

http://www.reddit.com/r/ocaml/comments/1jmjwf/explain_me_gadts_like_im_5_or_like_im_an/

etc, but some of them are in Haskell, and others do not have a good comparison example between *no GADT* and *GADT*.

So what I would like is a simple yet good concrete example where I can see if without GADT, things are bad.

Can I have that please?

Comment: It allows tighter constraints on types. And the oft example is an ast, where some constructors may be parameterized by boolean or integers, et cetera.

Comment: There is no such bad situation: before 4.0, ocall did not have support for gadt,  and people where doing fine. Otoh, having gadt make certain things easier, or more efficient.

Comment: I would also like to point out a discussion on gadt that happened early 2013 on the caml mailing list: http://lwn.net/Articles/531953/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GADTs are useful for two reasons.

The first one (and the most common one) is about dynamic typing: you can add some dynamic typing without losing static checking of it. It is not simple though, but you can be sure through it that your type conditions will be met.
The simplest example of that is given in the [ocaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec238).
This was used for instance in the standard library to rewrite printf in a type safe manner (before that, it was a pretty horrible collection of Obj.magic)

The second reason you may want to use GADTs is when you have some complex invariant you want to maintain on your type structure. This is pretty hard to express though, and you often have to put a lot of effort to do that.
Well, I don't have any example handy, but I once saw a friend write down an implementation of AVL-trees were it was proven by the typing system that balancing was right, which is pretty cool.

For more one the GADT feature, and its good use cases, You can read the pretty good [blog post](http://mads-hartmann.com/ocaml/2015/01/05/gadt-ocaml.html) by Mads Hartmann.

Comment: Could u please give an example? For a contrast of with and without?

Comment: Well, apart from the blog post of Mads Hartmann, you can try to lookup the anctient and new codes for Printf in the standard distribution. See https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/camlinternalFormatBasics.ml and the printf.ml file (same directory) then compare with the 4.00 branch (before the GADT format was here).

Comment: The blog post by Mads Hartmann is really excellent. It explains the idea very well.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also in a search of good application of GADT, as most of the time, when I use them sooner or later I discover, that the same can be done without them, and usually in a much more cleaner way. So, this is not a complete survey, just a bit of my own experience.

1. Universal values, aka existentials. They allow you to create heterogenous containers and typesafe serialization. See, for examples Core's `Univ` and `Univ_map` modules.
2. Type-safe evaluators for syntax trees. Here GADTs are useful to remove some runtime checks.
3. Pure and type-safe `Printf` [implementation](https://ocaml.org/meetings/ocaml/2013/proposals/formats-as-gadts.pdf), that is already a part of OCaml, was also rewritten using GADT

Here is a real life [example](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/lib/bap_image/bap_table.mli#L119) of how GADT can be used. In the example, I use GADT to specify table relations, e.g., `one_to_one`, `one_to_many`, etc. Depending on the used relation the function type is inferred accordingly. For example, `one_to_maybe_one` relation, returns a function `'a -> 'b option`, `one_to_many` creates a function with `'a -> 'b list`. The same can be achieved by just creating several different functions, like `link_one_to_one`, `link_one_to_many`, etc instead of one function `link ~one_to:relation`. So, one can consider this approach as arguable.

Comment: could you please extend your answer by explain why `the same can be done without them, and usually in a much more cleaner way`. If it is true, then why 4.00 added GADT? Also could you please give a  simpler demonstration?

Comment: I think that you misread me. I'm not claiming that GADT in general are useless. I'm claiming that in many everyday tasks you shouldn't use them, especially if there is a cleaner solution without them. This statement can be extended to first-class modules, functors, classes. But that's not to say, that they're useless. For example, universal values (without hacks) are impossible without GADTs.